# Rails/ActiveRecord sort by particular value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there any convenient way in Rails 3.2 to order an ActiveRecord relation by moving records with a particular value for a particular field to the front of the relation? For instance, if `MyModel` has an attribute `country`, I would like to sort relations returned by any query with records having `country='Spain'` to the front of the relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this.  Obviously 'name, id' would depend on your model and requirements.

```
MyModel.order("country = 'Spain' DESC, name, id")
```

Comment: @RichardStokes It should move them all to the front.  Can you share some code?