# SQL ORDER BY LIKE

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is similar to my previous question located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073194/rails-activerecord-sort-by-particular-value).Is there any way in SQL (using ActiveRecord) that you can order a relation using the LIKE operator? For instance, I'm querying a relation where one of the columns is a long string that typically contains many comma-separated-values. I would like to order the resulting relation by ordering to the front the records whose value for the aforementioned column matches a smaller string using LIKE (e.g. if my variable is "Spain", then I would like a record with a value like "Ireland, Spain, France" to be ordered to the front of the relation).

I tried this in active record with something like `MyModel.order("country_preferences LIKE ?", country)`, but got an SQL error. What is the correct way to perform this kind of ordering?

*Update* (extracted from comments):

Using PostgreSQL 9.1. Current SQL error here: http://pastie.org/8037147 .

5 records where country_preference = "Ireland, Spain, France", 5 records where country_preference = "Ireland, Germany, France". Given a particular country, would like to return a relation where records whose country_preferences string contains this country are ordered to the front.

Comment: Examples.  Example input, Current output, Desired output.  Also, give the SQL error you got.

Comment: 5 records where country_preference = "Ireland, Spain, France", 5 records where country_preference = "Ireland, Germany, France". Given a particular country, would like to return a relation where records whose country_preferences string contains this country are ordered to the front.

Comment: Current SQL error can be found here: http://pastie.org/8037147

Comment: If I got you correctly, this is what you want 
MyModel.where("country_preferences LIKE ?", "%#{country}%").order("country_preferences")

Comment: Does this not exclude all records where "country_preferences LIKE?", "%{country}" returns false? I'd like to return all records, just with the matching ones ordered to the front.

Comment: @ErminDedovic For future reference, wrap your code in \` and it will code block it `like this`

Comment: @RichardStokes What database do you use?

Comment: @ErminDedovic Postgresql 9.1

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that ActiveRecord's `order` doesn't support placeholders so you'll have to deal with the `?` by hand, sigh. Something nasty like this should make it go:

```
c = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(country)
MyModel.order("country_preferences LIKE '%' || #{c} || '%'")
```

You could combine this with [Goat_CO's CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074565/479863) if you don't want to rely on boolean ordering.

Comment: Very late to the party here, but I'd warn against string interpolation in database interfaces.  They have a nasty habit of becoming SQL injection vectors.

Comment: @RaySir That's why you have to do it carefully and use the database interface's quoting/escaping mechanisms. And sometimes you have to do it the ugly way because the only database interface you have is too limited and simple minded to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if a SQL answer is helpful, but you can use a CASE statement in your order by, necessary criteria isn't clear from your question, but perhaps this will help:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN country_preference LIKE '%Ireland%' THEN 1
              WHEN country_preference LIKE '%Spain%' THEN 2
              WHEN country_preference LIKE '%France%' THEN 3
              ELSE 4
          END
```

Answer (score 0):

> e.g. if my variable is "Spain", then I would like a record with a value like "Ireland, Spain, France" to be ordered to the front of the relation

You need a case statement, for that. It might look like this in Rails:

```
MyModel.order("CASE WHEN country LIKE '%' || ? || '%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END", country)
```

Though I'm honestly not 100% on the latter. The SQL, though, should look like this:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
order by case
         when country like '%Spain%' then 0
         else 1
         end
```

Do note that this is **NOT** an efficient query, though. The order by clause basically guarantees that no efficient index will be used to fetch the top 10 rows.

Comment: AR doesn't understand placeholders in `.order`, sigh. Keep in mind that AR handles placeholder itself using string mangling, it doesn't actually send them to the database.

Comment: Aye. Should be fixed, based on your own answer. :-P

Comment: All the scorn and derision heaped on AR by database people is (IMO) deserved. I use it but I swear at it and go straight to SQL an awful lot.

Comment: @muistooshort: fwiw, it's not much worse than other ORMs (Sequel being the only notable exception I'm aware of)... :D

Comment: I've written a few ORMs, they were all crap too :)

Answer (score 0):

> if my variable is "Spain", then I would like a record with a value like "Ireland, Spain, France" to be ordered to the front of the relation.

In that case, assign weights to the values according to your variable and ORDER by it.

```
 DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(20) = '%Spain%'

SELECT Column1 ,
       CASE WHEN Column1 LIKE @test
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
       END [Weight]
FROM Table
ORDER BY [Weight] DESC
```

If you dont want the 'weight' column show up, create a subquery on top of this query and leave out the 'weight' column.