# Rails sort particular value at the top

Tags: ruby-on-rails

build_histories (name, status, updated_at)

```
foo1, Queued, 2017-01-08 13:46:59
foo2, Failed, 2017-01-02 13:46:59
foo3, Success,2017-01-03 13:46:59
foo4, Queued, 2017-01-04 13:46:59
foo5, Failed, 2017-01-05 13:46:59
foo6, Success,2017-01-09 13:46:59
```

I tried this and it returns

```
BuildHistory.joins(app_build: :app).where("build_histories.bundle like ?","%#{params}%").order("CASE WHEN status = 'Queued' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,  status", "updated_at DESC")

foo1, Queued, 2017-01-08 13:46:59
foo4, Queued, 2017-01-04 13:46:59 
foo2, Failed, 2017-01-02 13:46:59
foo5, Failed, 2017-01-05 13:46:59
foo3, Success,2017-01-03 13:46:59
foo6, Success,2017-01-09 13:46:59
```

But I want to sort it as "Queued" always at the top and after that "Failed/Success" should be there by `updated_at desc` order

Example

```
foo1, Queued, 2017-01-08 13:46:59
foo4, Queued, 2017-01-04 13:46:59
foo6, Success,2017-01-09 13:46:59
foo5, Failed, 2017-01-05 13:46:59
foo3, Success,2017-01-03 13:46:59 
foo2, Failed, 2017-01-02 13:46:59
```

For reference: I tried based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637983/order-alphabetically-but-with-one-value-at-the-top)

Tried with the following

```
BuildHistory.joins(app_build: :app).where("build_histories.bundle like ?","%#{params}%").select("*, CASE WHEN build_histories.status = 'Queued' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as tmp_order").order("tmp_order, build_histories.updated_at desc")
```

I am able to get the result but in status column I am getting status = 1 or 2 instead of "Queued/Success/Failure"

Kindly Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails/ActiveRecord sort by particular value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073194/rails-activerecord-sort-by-particular-value)

Comment: @IceMan Thanks, BuildHistory.joins(app_build: :app).where("build_histories.bundle like ?","%#{params}%").select("*, CASE WHEN build_histories.status = 'Queued' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as tmp_order").order("tmp_order, build_histories.updated_at desc")

I am able to get the result but in status column I am getting status = 1 or 2 instead of "Queued/Success/Failure"

Comment: My answer was only to help with ordering, there is btw a much better answer posted after mine. However, the columns themselves don't change, is status an integer in your db?

Comment: status is not an integer, I tried with others solution. it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `MySql` you can try following order by [`field`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244028/sql-order-by-list-of-strings)

```
.order("FIELD(status, 'Queued'), updated_at DESC")
```

For postgres

```
.order("status = 'Queued' DESC, updated_at DESC")
```

Comment: Is there something similar for Postgres?

Comment: Not sure, may be you can check https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/48280D75.4070902%40lelarge.info

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
BuildHistory.order("CASE WHEN status = 'Queued' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END", "updated_at DESC")
```

Note: I've not checked the code myself, but I think it should work.